# Postgres ограничить время запроса в SQL

Tags: postgresql

если я напишу

```
set statement_timeout to 1000; select * from bigtable
```

то это ограничит время действия только этого скрипта? или моей сессии? или глобально для всего сервера?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[документация](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-set.html)

> If SET (or equivalently SET SESSION) is issued within a transaction that is later aborted, the effects of the SET command disappear when the transaction is rolled back. Once the surrounding transaction is committed, the effects will persist until the end of the session, unless overridden by another SET.

Т.е. это изменение настройки на сессию.

Если `set` был вызван внутри транзакции и транзакция была отменена, то значение настройки откатится на предыдущее. При коммите транзакции или вызове вне транзакции - будет продолжать действовать на текущую сессию и настройка может быть изменена другим set'ом.